# How to sign my apk with SHA1DSA using gradle.bat

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I can see that gradle **assembleProductionRelease** has following options to sign the apk

```
> ./gradlew assembleRelease \
> -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$KEYFILE \
> -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$STORE_PASSWORD \
> -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS \
> -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
```

By default it signs with MD5withRSA, but the keystore i have, uses SHA1withDSA. I can't find a way to pass this property to gradle, as we pass other properties like password, alias etc. (as shown above).

Can someone help me to know whether any such property exist for gradle?

Answer (score 1):

When you create SHA certificate its storing into .android folder. Please check the path where your keystore file is located. and give that file path in above code.

Comment: I am not signing it through Android studio. I am using batch file which uses finally graddle.bat with the parameters mentioned. The error I m getting is 

   java.security.InvalidKeyException: Not an RSA key: DSA

These keystore files are not in .android folder but some other path in the build system. I was just thinking that as we pass other properties we will have a way to pass digest algorithm as well..

Comment: Can anyone please comment on this